# Getting the length of a array by implementing this interface method? (Beginner)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, interface, constructor

I just wanted to know what way can I write the method

```
@Override
public int length() {
    return this.length();
    // TODO implement
}
```

So that when you call something like a.length() or s.length() it will return the length? (Here s and a are arrays)

My problem -

I was hardcoding it to

```
return a.length;
```

and hence this wasn't working for some other named array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't modify or extend array types. Use the `length` field.

Comment: Arrays have `.length`, Collections have `.size()` .  Do you really need anything else?

Comment: If you want to know the length of an array, you need to know how many items there are in the array.

Comment: It might help to see the code you are trying to use this with.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array as a parameter.

```
public int getLength(Object[] array) {
  return array.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to extend array types, but if you really want to add extra methods to an array, you could create a wrapper class like this:

```
public class Wrapper {
    private int[] someArray;

    public Wrapper(int size) {
        someArray = new int[size];
    }

    public int length() {
        return someArray.length;
    }

    public void addElem(int elem, int index) {
        someArray[index] = elem;
    }

    //Other methods...
}
```

But instead of doing that, you might as well use a class like `java.util.ArrayList`, as that would provide you with about the same functionality.